# Python: "if closest to 1"

Tags: python, logic

I am doing some calculations on a dictionary.
But the important thing is I want to make a if-condition that kind of says

"if **x** has a value that is closer to 1 (or equal to 1) than **variable**"

kind of hard to explain, but hope you understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [absolute value](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs):

```
if abs(x-1) < abs(variable-1):
    ...
```

since absolute value of `x-1` is the distance between `x` and `1`, and similarly absolute value of `variable-1` is the distance between `variable` and `1`.